# How to Create Nested Array in jQuery using .each()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops

I have a case I'd like to solve.
so what I want to create is a nested array with structure like this:

([0]=>1([0]=>3,[1]=>4), [1]=>3([0]=>3,[1]=>4)).

this is the script I use:

```
$('li.dd-head-section').each(function() {
  var id = $(this).data('id');
  sub_section = id;
  $('li.dd-head-section[data-id="'+id+'"] li.dd-sub-section').each(function() {
   sub_section = $(this).data('id');
  });
});
```

I use two .each() in order to get the result that I want but the script I use always give me this result:

[1, 3, 4, 3, 2, 5]

instead of what I want which is:

([0]=>1([0]=>3,[1]=>4), [1]=>3([0]=>3,[1]=>4)).

so is there any way to do that in jquery? I've been searching for the way to make this possible but I haven't got any solution yet so any help will be very very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
var menuArray = [], subArray;

  $('li.dd-head-section').each(function() {
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    subArray = [];
    $('li.dd-head-section[data-id="'+id+'"] li.dd-sub-section').each(function() {
      var sub_id = $(this).data('id');
      subArray.push(sub_id);
    });
    menuArray[id] = subArray;
  });
```